# Store HTML files in a document library - how to prevent SharePoint adding "ghosting" code

Tags: 2013, document-library, html

I am storing HTML files in a SharePoint document library (2013). Unfortunately, every time I upload a file, SharePoint is adding some code, the same as here:
[Why is SPD adding content to my file?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30626/why-is-spd-adding-content-to-my-file)

I am not using SharePoint Designer, but Windows Explorer. Those HTML files are not part of any SharePoint pages, they should be treated as any other documents in a document library.

Is there any way to disable the ghosting functionality for a specific document library (or a site collection) so the files content remain as original?

Or maybe a different way of storing HTML files in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: what is it adding to your html file?

Comment: The same code as in here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30626/why-is-spd-adding-content-to-my-file

Comment: Why does it bother you?

Comment: The files are stored in an external source and the source is periodically updated. I want to create a schedule task to check if the files I have in SharePoint are different to those in source and get all which are new or updated. The problem is that the comparison says that all the files are different all the time.

Comment: how are you comparing?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are using the html files for, you can try changing the extension. For example, call a file `content.html.txt`.

One thing I store html files for is to link them to content editor web parts. In that case the extension doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that this is SharePoints' way of storing metadata in your file. SharePoint also does this to your word files. This is desired behaviour.

Comment: How can this be desired behavior?

Comment: It's desired by sharepoint ;) So if you download and upload the file, the metadata gets merged.

Comment: "desired behavior" my ass.